# Difference between ^ Operator in JS and Python

Tags: javascript, python, bit-manipulation, xor

I need to port some JS code which involves `Math.random()*2147483648)^(new Date).getTime()`. While it looks like for smaller numbers, the python function and the JS function are equivalent in function, but with large numbers like this, the values end up entirely different.

Python:

```
>>> 2147483647 ^ 1257628307380
1257075044427
```

Javascript:

```
> 2147483647 ^ 1257628307380
-1350373301
```

How can I get the Javascript value from python?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python has unlimited-precision integers, while Javascript is using a 32-bit integer.  You can manually apply a 32-bit limit to get the result you want:

```
def xor32bit(a, b):
    m = (a ^ b) % (2**32)
    if m > (2**16):
        m -= 2**32
    return m
```

Comment: Better use `1 << 32` or directly `4294967296` instead of `2**32`.

Comment: Using 4294967296 would be silly—it kills readability. 2**32 is not absurdly expensive and it probably constant-folded. 1<<32 makes easily as much sense.

Comment: I just checked, and Python 3.1 constant-folds `2**16` and `2**32`.

Comment: Yes, it seems this was introduced in Python 2.5.  2.3 and 2.4 compute the value in bytecode, but 2.5 computes it in the compiler and the bytecode simply loads the constant value.

Answer (score 4):

Easiest way would be to use ctypes to get the same overflow behavior as Javascript:

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> ctypes.c_int(1257075044427)
c_long(-1350373301)
```

To get the value:

```
>>> ctypes.c_int(1257075044427).value
-1350373301
```