# Replicating Javascript bitwise operation in Python

Tags: javascript, python, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to replicate a simple bitwise Javascript operation in Python.

[Javascript]

```
> 0xA867Df55
  2825379669
> 0xA867Df55 ^ 0
  -1469587627
```

[Python]

```
>>> 0xA867DF55
2825379669L
>>> 0xA867DF55 ^ 0
2825379669L
```

Having read the following:

[Bitwise OR in ruby vs javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14898998/bitwise-or-in-ruby-vs-javascript)

it sounds like the issue here is that 0xA867Df55 (2825379669) in Javascript is larger than the largest signed 32-bit int (2147483647), which is causing an unexpected Javascript result.

The mail then goes on to suggest:

"If for some reason you wanted to reproduce that in Ruby, you would AND your number with 1FFFFFFFF so you're only operating on the least significant 32 bits and then OR it by 0 (which does nothing but would give you the same result)."

But if I try this:

```
>>> (0xA867DF55 & 0x1FFFFFFF) ^ 0
141025109L
```

I simply need to replicate the Javascript behaviour in Python. Can anyone suggest an appropriate bitwise operation ?

Thanks.

Comment: `import ctypes;ctypes.c_int(0xA867DF55 ^ 0).value`

Related : [Difference between ^ Operator in JS and Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694507/difference-between-operator-in-js-and-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about converting from uint32 to int32.

```
import struct
print struct.unpack('i', struct.pack('I', 0xA867Df55))[0]
```

**OUTPUT**

```
-1469587627
```

Or as @Ashwini suggests:

```
import ctypes
print ctypes.c_int(0xA867DF55 ^ 0).value
```

**OUTPUT**

```
-1469587627
```

Comment: Great, thx; I'll take the first option as ctypes isn't included on App Engine

Comment: You don't need any modules, `if(n & (1<<31)):n -= (1<<32)`